# C# calling a static method

Tags: c#, static

So I'm a java developer new to C# and I can't seem to get this trivial thing working. I have a Tests class which tests a method in another class. For convenience, I made these static so not to rely on any instantiation. For some reason though, my Tests class can't seem to find my Kata class.

```
namespace Codewars
{
   public class Program
   {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
     }

     public static string HoopCount(int n)
     {
        if (n >= 10)
        {
            return "Great, now move on to tricks";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Keep at it until you get it";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Test:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Codewars
{
    [TestFixture]
    class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public static void FixedTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("Keep at it until you get it", Kata.HoopCount(6), "Should work for 6");
            Assert.AreEqual("Great, now move on to tricks", Kata.HoopCount(22), "Should work for 22");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are calling Kata.HoopCount, but your class is named Program, not Kata. You would have to use Program.HoopCount. There is also no reason for your FixedTest method to be static.

Comment: Oh, that's stupid of me! I did use the built in renaming tool though, shouldn't it automaticly rename all references?

Comment: It should, unless you did it right. Maybe you did not confirm the renaming, just renamed the class and clicked away in the editor (just a guess)

Answer (score 2):

Your static method is declared inside Program, not Kata, so you should refer to it as `Program.HoopCount(someint)`